# Credentials when Installing Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I am attempting to install a C# windows service project using a VisualStudio.Net deployment project.

To run the deployment project I right-click and select "install" from the context menu, the install wizard runs and eventually prompts me with a "Set Service Login" dialog which asks for username & password.

When I install a service using the sc utility from the command line, I don't have to provide credentials.

Do I have to create a login just for this service?  I'd prefer to use "Local System" or "Network Service" (not sure what the difference is) as other services do.

Comment: in ProjectInstaller Right click the serviceProcessInstaller  => properties set account to LocalSystem

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Add this code to your private void `InitializeComponent()` method in `projectInstaller.Designer.cs` file in your windows service project.

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

if the definition of you process installer is:

```
private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1;
```

Comment: @anthares I need to run the service as current user, how can I fix that? I use: ServiceAccount.User but get the password request when Install it...

Comment: As the code spot for that is in designer-generated code I just did the same thing by opening the designer, getting properties on the serviceProcessInstaller1 object, then selecting LocalSystem in the drop-down for Account.

Comment: I prefer @David 's answer below, using the designer.... Does roughly the same thing, but I think that method is better.

Comment: and remember to rebuild

Answer (score 24):

Check this Link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Pay attention to this section: **To create the installers for your service**

*Make changes to your ServiceProcessInstaller:*

**In the designer, click ServiceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual Basic project, or serviceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual C# project. Set the Account property to LocalSystem. This will cause the service to be installed and to run on a local service account.**

Comment: This takes precedence over setting it via code in the projectInstaller.Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 4):

In the project that contains the service, add an Installer class. Make it look something like this:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem; // Or whatever account you want

        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller
        {
            DisplayName = "Insert the display name here",
            StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic, // Or whatever startup type you want
            Description = "Insert a description for your service here",
            ServiceName = "Insert the service name here"
        };

        Installers.Add(_serviceProcessInstaller);
        Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Commit(savedState);

        // This will automatically start your service upon completion of the installation.
        try
        {
            var serviceController = new ServiceController("Insert the service name here");
            serviceController.Start();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Insert a message stating that the service couldn't be started, and that the user will have to do it manually");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the solution explorer, right-click on the deployment project and select "View > Custom Actions". Right-click on Custom Actions, and select "Add Custom Action..." Pick the Application Folder and select the primary output of the project that contains the service. Now the custom actions (`Commit` from above) will be executed upon installation. You can add the additional methods (`Install`, `Rollback`, `Uninstall`) if you need other custom actions.

Comment: I don't get it ? How this is going to help him, to set the system account to be executer of the service ?

Comment: That's what I get for copying code from my project. {facepalm} In the `Install` method of my project's installer, I was setting the 'Account` property. It's fixed now...

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your ProjectInstaller
2. Right click the ServiceProcessInstaller and choose properties
3. From the Account drop-down, under Misc, select the account you want your service to run as

For details of the different accounts and their privileges see the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx

Comment: I can't see Account drop-down under Misc, VS 2010

Comment: He meant ServiceProcessInstaller, not ProcessInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is click on your serviceProjectInstaller and set it on properties window.

[image]