# Why does .NetFramework console exe program shut down by itself after 1 day idle?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, netmq

I have a Console application that is ran on the background. Its a simple server that built using `NetMQ` library and `NLogger` that works locally.

I ran the program using taskScheduler with the following command `schtasks /create /sc ONSTART /tn "TheServer" /tr "C:\\Temp\TheServer.exe" /ru System`

As you can se, now it will start every time the desktop is turned on and it will run as System (It means that we can see `TheServer.exe` is running as background through Task Manager)

Question:

My timeline was like the follows:

1. My PC was on on Friday morning (starting of Business day - 09:00 in the morning)
2. I didn't turn off my PC on Friday before I go back from work
3. Monday morning, I checked my PC and `TheServer` is already gone

Does anyone know why it happens and how to prevent it?

---

FYI, I write my code as follows

`Program.cs`

```
class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static readonly NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        
        ...

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var inst = Server.GetInstance();
                inst.Bind();
                inst.Run();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.Message);
                log.Error(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

`Server.cs`

```
class Server
    {
        private NetMQ.Sockets.ResponseSocket rSocket = new NetMQ.Sockets.ResponseSocket();
        static readonly NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        ...

        public void Bind()
        {
            try
            {
                //bind is only for the Responder or The Server
                rSocket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:32325");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Error(e.Message);
                log.Error(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                 var message = server.ReceiveFrameString();
                 Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", message);
                 // processing the request
                 Thread.Sleep(100);
                 Console.WriteLine("Sending World");
                 server.SendFrame("World");
            }
        }
    }
```

I wrap my code at `Program.cs` with try-catch. But nothing written in the log

Then

I tried to find some information at the Window's Event Viewer. But there are no related information why `TheServer.exe` stopped

---

Update:
Looks like I found what @PMF means.
[image]

Then one extra question. . .

Is there any way to do that through command prompt?

I tried to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create Looks like if I didn't set the `/du` when create the task, it will be forever (?). CMIIW

---

UPDATE

So yes, we decided to recreate this `TheServer.exe` as Windows Service. Thanks for your input and opinions.

Comment: Check the task scheduler settings. There's one setting that would terminate the job after running for more than a specified time (don't know what the default is, though). For what you intend to do, I would recommend using the service management, not the task scheduler. The task scheduler is for short-living processes that need to run once in a while, not for background tasks that should run typically forever.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for your comment. I think I found what you mean. If task scheduler is not the answer to run the background tasks forever, do you have any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Task scheduler is designed to run short tasks regularly. An application that potentially runs forever is called a service. You could just run it at system startup or when a user logs in or (with .Net Framework) you can create a Windows Service application that Windows itself can manage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: @MHRahman Check phuzi's comment. You should run your application as a _service_ rather than a task. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427395/run-the-console-application-as-service)

Comment: @phuzi Thanks for your input. Looks like we are planning to migrate our Console Program into Service soon

Comment: @PMF thanks for the attached link. It looks like I need several references to speed up my migration process